# Restrict access to Firebase Hosting content

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm building a set of rest APIs on firebase.
I've generated docs with both swagger (for "external" docs) and jsdoc (for "internal" ones). Hence, from jsdoc, I have a bunch of HTML pages that I want to deploy onto FB hosting, but I want to restrict access to such pages only to some authenticated users.

For dynamic content, e.g. swagger-generated, I've easily solved as follows.

```
doc_fun.use(
  '/rest',
  basicAuth({
    users: {'user': 'password'},
    challenge: true,
  }),
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec)
)
exports.docs = functions.https.onRequest(doc_fun)
```

I'm looking for (possibly similar) solution for static content. Something like:

```
doc_fun.use(
  '/jsdoc', 
  basicAuth({
    users: {'user': 'password'},
    challenge: true,
  }), 
  express.static('public/jsdoc')
)
```

(which, of course, doesn't work)

Comment: Please check the below link. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753740/authentication-for-firebase-hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the last comment by Renaud, I've managed to find a simple workaround.

I post it here so that, maybe, it can be useful to someone else.

- I put my 'jsdoc' folder with all its HTML static content inside 'functions' one
- I've set express.static path parameter to './jsdoc'

index.js:

```
doc_fun.use(
  '/jsdoc', 
   basicAuth({
     users: {'user': 'password'},
     challenge: true,
   }), 
   express.static('./jsdoc') //current folder is 'functions'
 )
```

firebase.json:

```
...,
"rewrites": [
  ...,
  {
    "source": "/docs/**",
    "function": "docs"
  }
],
...
```

And now `http://my_project.cloudfunctions.net/docs/jsdoc/` is serving my static content only to authenticated visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You will find everything you need in this official Cloud Functions [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api), which shows "how to authenticate access to a JSON API to only allow access to data for a specific Firebase user".

More precisely, it shows how the Express middleware "validates Firebase ID Tokens passed in the Authorization HTTP header".

Comment: Thank you @Renaud, but my problem is making the cloudfunction access the 'public' hosting folder: I keep getting 404, also in the cloudfunction logs.

Comment: If you generate the "static" files through the Cloud Function it should be ok. It seems strange to generate a static file on the fly but with Firebase Hosting I think it is the only way to do what you are looking for.